# Length of a list of points

Tags: python, python-2.7

For a given list of points that make a line I want to compute the length of it. For example for:

```
[(1,0),(5,6),(9,6),(5,2)]
```

these are just a list of connected points. How can I have an automated method for computing them?
the code that create the linestring:

```
import math
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class LineString(Point):
    def __init__(self, *points):
        #~ self.points=points
        self.points = []
        for point in points:
            if not isinstance(point, Point):
                point = Point(*point)
            self.points.append(point)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Tests for LineString
    # ===================================
    lin1 = LineString((1, 1), (0, 2))


    assert lin1.length() == math.sqrt(2.0)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what the list is actually containing?

Comment: Please provide examples of lists and the corresponding expected results.

Comment: well, I'll add the code in a min

Comment: rule of thumb: minimal examples are better.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this solution. I iterate on pairs and use [`math.hypot`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.hypot)

```
l = [(1,0),(5,6),(9,6),(5,2)]

from itertools import tee, izip
from math import hypot

def pairwise(iterable):
  a, b = tee(iterable)
  next(b, None)
  return izip(a, b)

distance = 0
# iterate on pairs of points
for prev_point, next_point in pairwise(l):
  prev_x, prev_y = prev_point
  next_x, next_y = next_point
  distance += hypot(next_x - prev_x, next_y - prev_y)

print distance
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sum` and `math.hypot`:

```
>>> from math import hypot
>>> l = [(1, 0), (5, 6), (9, 6), (5, 2)]
>>> sum(hypot(x1 - x2, y1 - y2) for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in zip(l, l[1:]))
16.86795680042036
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

line = np.array([(1,0),(5,6),(9,6),(5,2)], float)
print np.sqrt(np.sum((line[1:] - line[:-1])**2, -1)).sum()
```

or list comprehensions:

```
line = [(1,0),(5,6),(9,6),(5,2)]

sum(((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)**0.5 for (x1,y1),(x2,y2) in zip(line[:-1], line[1:]))
```

**edit**:

By using your classes, you can define a `dist()` method in `Point` and `length` in `LineString`:

```
import math
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def dist(self, point):
        return math.hypot(self.x-point.x, self.y-point.y)

class LineString(Point):
    def __init__(self, *points):
        #~ self.points=points
        self.points = []
        for point in points:
            if not isinstance(point, Point):
                point = Point(*point)
            self.points.append(point)

    @property
    def length(self):
        return sum(p1.dist(p2) for p1, p2 in zip(self.points[1:], self.points[:-1]))

line = LineString((1,0),(5,6),(9,6),(5,2))
print line.length
```

Comment: More succinct NumPy solution: `np.hypot(*np.diff(line.T)).sum()`